# Doubled tasks in Activiti process

Tags: apache-camel, activiti, apache-servicemix

I've got an Activiti code (Activiti 5.19 run with Camel on Servicemix) running in production and face some peculiar problem: sometimes I've got cases of doubled tasks in an execution (one of them is even tripled). It seems to have  no clear pattern. What I've tested my code would throw an exception if any javascript call service to close the same task twice for some reason.

The doubled tasks neither can be completed (resulting "UserTask should not be signalled before complete" exception) nor deleted because the tasks are part of the running execution.

I cannot figure out what could cause such an effect and how to get rid of the redundant tasks in order to finish the damaged processes.

Is there possible to just delete the later records (with the highest task id) in the act_ru_task?

Anybody could help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
    xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
    typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath"
    targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
    <collaboration id="Collaboration">
        <participant id="pool1" name="Pool" processRef="process_pool1"></participant>
    </collaboration>
     <process id="new_marketing" name="marketing" isExecutable="true" activiti:candidateStarterGroups="marketing,task_manager">
    <laneSet id="laneSet_new_marketing">
      <lane id="lane1" name="marketing">
        <flowNodeRef>usertask1</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>startevent1</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>exclusivegateway1</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>usertask2</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>usertask3</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>usertask4</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>endevent1</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>exclusivegateway2</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>exclusivegateway3</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>usertask5</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>usertask6</flowNodeRef>
        <flowNodeRef>endevent2</flowNodeRef>
      </lane>
    </laneSet>

    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>

    <userTask id="usertask1" name="Status_0" activiti:assignee="${employeeName}" activiti:candidateGroups="marketing" activiti:dueDate="${dueDate}">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="actionsForm" name="actions" type="enum" writable="false">
          <activiti:value id="cancel" name="cancel"></activiti:value>
          <activiti:value id="accepted" name="accepted"></activiti:value>
          <activiti:value id="wait" name="wait"></activiti:value>
        </activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow12" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>

    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusivegateway1" name="Exclusive Gateway"></exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="exclusivegateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="usertask2" name="Status_10" activiti:assignee="${employeeName}">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:formProperty id="actionsForm" name="actions" type="enum" writable="false">
              <activiti:value id="cancel" name="cancel"></activiti:value>
              <activiti:value id="proceed" name="proceed"></activiti:value>
              <activiti:value id="application" name="application"></activiti:value>
              <activiti:value id="accepted" name="accepted"></activiti:value>
              <activiti:value id="wait" name="wait"></activiti:value>
            </activiti:formProperty>
        </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="usertask2">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'accepted'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="usertask3" name="Status_1" activiti:assignee="${employeeName}" activiti:dueDate="${dueDate}"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" name="Wait" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="usertask3">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'wait'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="usertask3" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="usertask4" name="Status_1000" activiti:assignee="${employeeName}"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" name="GiveUp" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="usertask4">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'cancel'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow6" sourceRef="usertask4" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusivegateway2" name="Exclusive Gateway"></exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="usertask2" targetRef="exclusivegateway2"></sequenceFlow>

    <endEvent id="endevent2" name="End"></endEvent>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow10" sourceRef="exclusivegateway2" targetRef="usertask2">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'wait'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow11" name="GiveUp" sourceRef="exclusivegateway2" targetRef="usertask4">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'cancel'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>


    <sequenceFlow id="flow8" sourceRef="exclusivegateway2" targetRef="usertask5">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'application'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow13" sourceRef="exclusivegateway2" targetRef="usertask6">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'proceed' || action == 'accepted'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="usertask5" name="Status_50" activiti:assignee="${employeeName}">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:formProperty id="actionsForm" name="actions" type="enum" writable="false">
              <activiti:value id="cancel" name="cancel"></activiti:value>
              <activiti:value id="accepted" name="accepted"></activiti:value>
            </activiti:formProperty>
        </extensionElements>
    </userTask>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow14" sourceRef="usertask5" targetRef="exclusivegateway3"></sequenceFlow>

    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusivegateway3" name="Exclusive Gateway"></exclusiveGateway>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow15" sourceRef="exclusivegateway3" targetRef="usertask6">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'accepted'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>

    <userTask id="usertask6" name="Status_90" activiti:assignee="${employeeName}"></userTask>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow17" sourceRef="usertask6" targetRef="endevent2">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'accepted'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow16" sourceRef="exclusivegateway3" targetRef="usertask4">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${action == 'cancel'}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>

  </process>
</definitions>
```

The problem was checked in Activiti database using the following query:

```
select * from act_ru_task t0 where t0.execution_id_ in (select id_ from act_ru_execution t1 where (select count(*) from act_ru_task t2 where t1.id_ = t2.execution_id_) > 1);
```

Query presented 30 cases like this, below 3 of them (user logins anonimised):

```
     id_    | rev_ | execution_id_ | proc_inst_id_ |     proc_def_id_     |    name_    | parent_task_id_ | description_ | task_def_key_ | owner_ |  assignee_   |delegation_   | priority_ |      create_time_       |
     118399 |    1 | 118373        | 118373        | new_marketing:3:5004 | Status_50   |                 |              | usertask5     |        | auser        |              |        50 | 2017-08-08 08:46:28.771 |
     118396 |    1 | 118373        | 118373        | new_marketing:3:5004 | Status_50   |                 |              | usertask5     |        | auser        |              |        50 | 2017-08-08 08:46:28.769 |
     634792 |    1 | 453636        | 453636        | new_marketing:3:5004 | Status_1000 |                 |              | usertask4     |        | buser        |              |        50 | 2018-04-04 09:49:13.853 |
     634791 |    1 | 453636        | 453636        | new_marketing:3:5004 | Status_1000 |                 |              | usertask4     |        | buser        |              |        50 | 2018-04-04 09:49:13.853 |
     527864 |    1 | 527837        | 527837        | new_marketing:3:5004 | Status_90   |                 |              | usertask6     |        | cuser        |              |        50 | 2018-02-01 16:06:56.089 |
     527867 |    1 | 527837        | 527837        | new_marketing:3:5004 | Status_90   |                 |              | usertask6     |        | cuser        |              |        50 | 2018-02-01 16:06:56.092 |
```

Comment: your `.bpm.xml` file will be useful in finding the issue. can you please upload that?

Comment: hi, bpm xml added above

Comment: Can you log the execution and processInstance id for the tasks that are duplicated (tripled)? Can you confirm that they all belong to the same instance?

Comment: Here is result excerpt from Activiti database and my query (above).

Comment: Please note the creation time: it is always almost the same or even the same for each of the record pairs.

Comment: I had faced the same problem an year before. Could never resolve the issue. But it stopped happening after a few months ! I still have no idea why this occurs. May be you should contact Activiti Developers group for help.

Comment: Have you managed anyhow the duplicates? If there is any way to get rid of the duplicates the problem wouldn’t affect users really.